# getting address of the structure padded bytes

Tags: c, struct, padding

I was curious to know the values contained in the padded bytes in structure padding.

So i wrote the following code, but incrementing the pointer will point to the next structure member. How can we access the padded memory locations?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct /* __attribute__((__packed__))*/ test{
        int a;
        char b;
        int c;
};

 main(){
        struct test a;
        a.a = 10;
        a.b = 's';
        a.c = 15;

        printf("%d\n",sizeof(a));
        printf("address of first int is: %p \n",(void *)&a.a);
        printf("address of the first char is : %p\n",(void *)&a.b);
        printf("address of the second int is : %p\n",(void *)&a.c);

        printf("the value of char is: %c\n", a.b);

        int *p;
        p = (void *) &a.b;
        printf("%p\n",p);
        p++;
        printf("the value in the padded place is: %d\n",*p);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would use a `char*`.

Comment: Thanks that's what i wanted. What will be the default values in the padded bytes?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck ... which points to `&a` and iterates `sizeof(a)` steps.

Comment: Yes, by design/spec, incrementing a pointer to a type increases the memory address in the pointer by sizeof(type).  char* pB = &a.b;  and char* pC = (char*)&a.c;  then while pB < pC, show( *pB++ ), this will show the value in a.b and all memory spaces up to the location of a.c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `const unsigned char *`:

```
void print_hex(const void *data, size_t size)
{
  const unsigned char *src = data;
  while (size > 0)
  {
    printf("%02x ", *src++);
    --size;
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Use like so:

```
struct test a = { 10, 's', 15 };
print_hex(&a, sizeof a);
```